# Why is the depletion region formed by minority carriers?

Tags: transistors

While I was studying about the working of transistors I came across a term called the depletion region which stops the flow of electrons from one place to another. A doubt that came to me was why couldn't the majority carriers form a depletion region?

Comment: Because it's the majority carriers that are being depleted.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams:Thanks for your comment.But why couldn't the majority carriers form a barrier potential because they too possess an positive and negative potential isn't it?

Comment: They possibly could. But then it wouldn't be a "depletion region".

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams:why didn't the majority carriers formed a potential difference or what stopped them from producing one?

Comment: I would say that it's the fact that they'd rather be on the other side of the interface.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams:Do you mean that majority carriers wouldn't be present in the p-n juction or interface?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams:I couldn't get what you meant by the "other side of the interface".Is interface the 'p-n juction'.

Answer (score 4):

You don't mention a specific type of transistor so I am going to explain generally only the physical principles.

You can think of a transistor as two connected pn junctions.

You have holes flowing from the p-type region to the n-type region. Also you have electrons flow from the n-type to the p-type. When holes reach the n-type region they will disappear with electrons. So in the n-type region which was electrically neutral now there are going to be positive charges. The same thing happen in the p-type only with negative charges.

More precisely when you have the holes flow from p to n upon arrival in the n region they will be the minority carriers and the electrons the majority carriers. When there were no holes the n-type region was electrically neutral. Now the minority carriers (holes) disappear (connect) with the majority carriers (electrons) so now the n-type region is positive charged. As I mentioned the same goes for the p-type region but with negative charge at the end.

The formation of the depletion region in a pn junction:

[image]

A pn junction in forward bias:

[image]

And in reverse bias:

[image]

Comment: when does this happen i.e is it when the transistor is in off or on state?

Comment: This is when the transistor is in open circuit. In any case either on or off you will have a depletion region. But it will be of different width.

Comment: does that mean that they would be a depletion region even if you don't apply an bias voltage.

Comment: Yes it would be. Also it would be even if you apply bias or forward voltage but with different width in each case.

Comment: could you explain what you meant by  "n-type region is positive charged".does that mean full n region gets a postive charge or whether only a part of it.

Comment: No I meant that the part of the depletion region that is in the n-type region gets positive charged.

Comment: do you meant that the holes are dissappering or whether the holes are accumulated at the depletion region.

Comment: When you have a positive and a negative change then when I say disappear I mean that before there was one positive and one negative charge and that in the end there are no more +1-1=0.

Comment: if the hole disappear than how could the n region be positively charged?

Comment: The n-type in the beginning is neutral. Holes arrive and they will connect with some electrons. At the end there is going to be a positive charge as with the holes came an excess positive charge.

Comment: are you saying that at the time of formation of depletion layer the number of holes would be more than the number of electrons in n region.

Comment: In the n-type region the electrons are the majority carries so always there are going to be more electrons that holes. The reverse thing happens in the p-type region.

Comment: could you say then how could holes come with an excess positive charge.

Comment: Holes are by definition positive charged!

Comment: why can't holes in n-type move towards electrons in p-type.

Comment: As you have a lot of elementary questions and there is an extensive discussion in comments which isn't appropriate I would recommend to you to start reading the physical principles behind diodes and build up until transistors. There are a lot of excellent books concerning electronics like Sedra Smith or Jaeger. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer for this is in this image[image]

This shows that only when the majority carrier(s) transfer from one region to another,minory carriers in effect really produce the depletion region.